# useTheme hook outside of react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I made a ThemeProvider to change themes in my React native application, I want to use theme outside of react component

**ThemeContext.js**

```
const ThemeContext = createContext();

export const ThemeProvider = ({children}) => {
  const storedTheme = getMMKV('theme');
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(
    storedTheme ? themes[storedTheme] : themes?.light,
  );

  const toggleTheme = selectedTheme => {
    switch (selectedTheme) {
      case 'light':
        setTheme(themes?.light);
        break;
      ...
      ...
      default:
        setTheme(themes?.light);
        break;
    }
    storeMMKV('theme', selectedTheme);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{theme, toggleTheme}}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useTheme = () => {
  return useContext(ThemeContext);
};
```

I want to use theme value inside SomeComponent.styles.js

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: theme.primary,
    borderRadius: px(16),
    borderWidth: px(2),
    paddingHorizontal: px(10),
    borderColor: theme.buttonBorder,
    height: height,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach, you can use a function to create styles

SomeComponent.styles.js

```js
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const createStyles = (theme) => StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: theme.primary,
    borderRadius: px(16),
    borderWidth: px(2),
    paddingHorizontal: px(10),
    borderColor: theme.buttonBorder,
  },
});

export default createStyles;
```

And then use it in your components like this

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import createStyles from './SomeComponent.styles';
import { useTheme } from './ThemeContext';

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { theme } = useTheme();
  const styles = createStyles(theme);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* Your component code here */}
    </View>
  );
};
```